# zip/image File upload get corrupt when uploading on oracle cloud storage using springboot application

Tags: spring-boot

zip/image File upload get corrupt when uploading on oracle cloud storage using springboot application which is deployed on  oracle container cloud service. But in localhost STS zip/image upload is successful on oracle cloud storage without corrupt. Note:text file upload is working good in both place

```
Controller : @RequestMapping(value = "/v2.0/files/{filename}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(@PathVariable("filename") String fileName,
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @RequestHeader("record_type") String programName) {
        try {

            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (authentication != null) {
                User u = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
                User user = apiAuthUserService.getUserByName(u.getUsername());
                if (user == null) {
                    LOG.error("username from token can't be found in DB.");
                    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                            .body(Collections.singletonMap("error", "Unauthorized to perform operation."));
                } else {
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                            .setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, null));
                }

                String uploadFileName = fileName;
                String newUploadFileName = "";

                /*
                 * Create new filename using currentTime
                 */
                long currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                newUploadFileName = uploadFileName.substring(0, uploadFileName.lastIndexOf('.')) + "_" + currentTime
                        + uploadFileName.substring(uploadFileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
                newUploadFileName = newUploadFileName.replace(' ', '_');

                LOG.info("userDetails: " + "Tenant: " + user.getTenantId() + " UserName: " + user.getUsername());
                LOG.info("recordType: " + programName);
                LOG.info("uploadFileName: " + uploadFileName);
                LOG.info("newUploadFileName: " + newUploadFileName);

                /*
                 * Get the StorageCredentials using tenantId and get authenticationToken from
                 * Oracle
                 */
                StorageCredentials storageCredentials = storageCredentialsService
                        .getStorageCredentials(user.getTenantId(), programName.toUpperCase());

                if (storageCredentials == null) {
                    throw new Exception("storageCredentials is null");
                }

                String authenticationToken = AuthenticationUtil.getAuthenticationToken(storageCredentials);

                if (authenticationToken != null && authenticationToken.length() > 0) {
                    LOG.info("success: Cloud Storage Authentication Successful");

                    /*
                     * Call the upload cloud API and check the response
                     */
                    ResponseEntity<String> response = UploadUtil.uploadFile(authenticationToken, storageCredentials,
                            newUploadFileName, httpServletRequest.getInputStream());

                    if (response != null && response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CREATED) {
                        LOG.info("upload response: " + response);
                        /*
                         * Create custom response for returning
                         */
                        Map<String, String> uploadResponseMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        uploadResponseMap.put("date", response.getHeaders().get("Date").get(0));
                        uploadResponseMap.put("fileName", newUploadFileName);
                        uploadResponseMap.put("eTag", response.getHeaders().getETag());

                        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(uploadResponseMap);
                    } else {
                        LOG.error("error: Cannot save to cloud storage.");
                        // LOG.info("upload response: " + response);
                        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                                .body(Collections.singletonMap("error", "Cannot save to cloud storage."));
                    }

                } else {
                    LOG.error("error: Cloud Storage Authentication Failed");
                    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                            .body(Collections.singletonMap("error", "Cannot access cloud storage."));
                }

            } else {
                LOG.error("error: Unauthorized to perform operation.");
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        .body(Collections.singletonMap("error", "Unauthorized to perform operation."));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .body(Collections.singletonMap("error", e.getMessage()));
        }

    }
public static ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(String authenticationToken, StorageCredentials storageCredentials,
            String fileName, InputStream dataStream) throws IOException {

        if (storageCredentials != null) {
            // set headers
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
            headers.add(TOKEN_HEADER, authenticationToken);

            // set the body for the put request
            byte[] fileBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(dataStream);
            HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(fileBytes, headers);

            String uploadUrl = storageCredentials.getUrl() + "/v1/" + storageCredentials.getIdentityDomain() + "/"
                    + storageCredentials.getContainer() + "/" + fileName;
            LOG.info("upload Url " + uploadUrl);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
            requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);     
            restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory); 

            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uploadUrl, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity,
                    String.class);

            return response;
        } else {
            LOG.error("error: storageCredentials is null");
            return null;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you mention what the exception you got from it..?

Comment: It is spring boot application with spring security. I didn't see any exception. file(non text) was created but it was corrupted. Its size as well as byte array was changed. however we are able to open text file. So issue is with non text file(z.p/image/pdf). I have used "httpServletRequest.getInputStream()" to get file stream.

Comment: Can you paste your upload API code?

Comment: I have upload API code. Please look into it and let me know the error

Comment: Byte of correct zip file before upload is given below

Comment: PK    #‹Oò‡O£ý   j     SparkNew(1).csvuMnÄ F÷•zOÈßdIÀÓR%'RV¾ÿ-J¦š¦-xŸáÙb°ãhÝëwåŽY;¬„
y­€³ÄF‚ÁÑnö;ñ-øé)"ÿÐðçªYÚaVÖ£‘È¨Ê¨É¨í:¼E­ÓÊ|ðOLûŒ÷wÉxß8oØ© aCg|àÅÆµ7±¤ö ±u›WÙ­Ó€á,¤h]`ñk8ú=>¨ewB—Â5…>Q¦Ô²IJ-o u]SªKÞ^_ DÓö²îA–¢¿”òRŠŽ
 ¨A²ªA]ƒ¶¨Ž-[¿­Õ©z>^3«(šCWòëPK     #‹Oò‡O£ý   j                  SparkNew(1).csvPK      =   *

Comment: After API upload, Byte of generated  corrupted zip file is given below

Comment: PK    #ï¿½Oï¿½Oï¿½ï¿½   j     SparkNew(1).csvuï¿½Mnï¿½ Fï¿½ï¿½zOï¿½ï¿½dIï¿½ï¿½R%ï¿½'RVï¿½ï¿½-Jï¿½ï¿½ï¿½-xï¿½ï¿½ï¿½bï¿½ï¿½hï¿½ï¿½wï¿½ï¿½Y;ï¿½ï¿½
yï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Fï¿½ï¿½ï¿½nï¿½;ï¿½-ï¿½ï¿½)"ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Yï¿½aVÖ£ï¿½È¨Ê¨É¨ï¿½:ï¿½Eï¿½ï¿½ï¿½|ï¿½OLï¿½ï¿½ï¿½wï¿½xï¿½8oØ© aCg|ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½7ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½uï¿½ï¿½WÙ­Ó€ï¿½,ï¿½h]`ï¿½k8ï¿½=>ï¿½ewBï¿½ï¿½5ï¿½>Qï¿½Ô²IJ-o u]Sï¿½Kï¿½^_ Dï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Aï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Rï¿½ï¿½
 ï¿½Aï¿½ï¿½A]ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½-[ï¿½ï¿½Õ©z>^3ï¿½(ï¿½CWï¿½ï¿½PK     #ï¿½Oï¿½Oï¿½ï¿½   j                  SparkNew(1).csvPK      =   *

Comment: Instead of using rest template for API you can use Oracle cloud storage SDK to upload your file.

Comment: I have used cloud storage SDK. Same error, Still zip file has corrupted.

Comment: Where you tested the download API??

Comment: Using get API I have tested it. if upload the file from localhost sts tomcat then it is working good and i m able to download non corrupt zip file. But after deployment of application on Oracle container, It make zip file corrupt.